# When for given $p$ and $n$ we have $p^n \pmod{4}=1$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Consider $p$ is a prime odd number and $n$ is an integer positive number.

*My question:* Is there a condition over parameters $p$ and $n$ such that 
$p^n \equiv1\pmod{4}$ ?

Thanks for any suggestions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since $p$ is odd, either $p = 4k+1$ or $p=4k-1$ for some $k$. Applying the binomial theorem, we see that in the former case,
$$ p^n = (4k+1)^n = 1+ \sum_{j=1}^n \binom{n}{j} (4k)^j \equiv 1 \, (\text{mod } 4), $$
so the required condition holds for all such primes.
In the latter case,
$$ p^n = (4k-1)^n = (-1)^n + \sum_{j=1}^n \binom{n}{j} (4k)^j (-1)^{n-j} \equiv (-1)^n \, (\text{mod } 4), $$
so $n$ should be even.

Comment: I would very much appreciate for your nice solution.

Comment: @user0410 Glad that it helped!

Comment: If you reduce the prime $\mod{4}$ prior to exponentiation, you can avoid the need for the binomial expansion. $p\equiv \pm1 \mod{4}$, so $p^n\equiv (\pm1)^n\mod{4}$. Keeping proper track of the $\pm$ signs, you get the result given by MisterRiemann.

Comment: @KeithBackman Good point, not really sure how I managed to miss that!